# Trying to get data from class into main program

Tags: c#, class, return

I am new to C# so I apologise if the format of my code is wrong. Currently I am trying to work out how to return a value from a class that calculates the distance for my data.

Here is what I have so far, when I ask or two points however the only thing that comest out is DistanceGenerator.Coursework I can't see what I am doing wrong, any help?

```
namespace DistanceGenerator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //Displays data in correct Format

            List<float> inputList = new List<float>();
            TextReader tr = new StreamReader("c:/users/tom/documents/visual studio 2010/Projects/DistanceCalculator3/DistanceCalculator3/TextFile1.txt");
            String input = Convert.ToString(tr.ReadToEnd());
            String[] items = input.Split(',');
            Console.WriteLine("Point         Latitude        Longtitude       Elevation");

            for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i % 3 == 0)
                {
                    Console.Write((i / 3) + "\t\t");
                }

                Console.Write(items[i]);
                Console.Write("\t\t");

                if (((i - 2) % 3) == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }

            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();

            // Ask for two inputs from the user which is then converted into 6 floats and transfered in class Coordinates

            bool exit = false;
            do
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the two points that you wish to know the distance between:");
                string point = Console.ReadLine();
                string[] pointInput = point.Split(' ');

                int pointNumber = Convert.ToInt16(pointInput[0]);
                int pointNumber2 = Convert.ToInt16(pointInput[1]);

               double latitude = (Convert.ToDouble(items[pointNumber * 3]));
               double longtitude = (Convert.ToDouble(items[(pointNumber * 3) + 1]));
               double elevation = (Convert.ToDouble(items[(pointNumber * 3) + 2]));

               double latitude2 = (Convert.ToDouble(items[pointNumber2 * 3]));
               double longtitude2 = (Convert.ToDouble(items[(pointNumber2 * 3) + 1]));
               double elevation2 = (Convert.ToDouble(items[(pointNumber2 * 3) + 2]));


                //Calculate the distance between two points
                Distance curDistance = new Distance(latitude, longtitude, elevation, latitude2, longtitude2, elevation2);

                Console.WriteLine(curDistance);


                Console.WriteLine("If you wish to calculate another distance type 1 and return, if you wish to end the program, type -1.");

                string reset;

                do
                {
                    reset = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
                }
                while (reset != "1" && reset != "-1");

                if (reset == "-1") exit = true;
            }
            while (!exit);

        }
    }
}
```

//and here is the class

```
namespace DistanceGenerator
{
    class Distance
    {
        private double latitude;
        private double longtitude;
        private double elevation;
        private double latitude2;
        private double longtitude2;
        private double elevation2;

        public Distance(double latitude, double longtitude, double elevation, double latitude2, double longtitude2, double elevation2)
        {
            // TODO: Complete member initialization
            this.latitude = latitude;
            this.longtitude = longtitude;
            this.elevation = elevation;
            this.latitude2 = latitude2;
            this.longtitude2 = longtitude2;
            this.elevation2 = elevation2;
        }

        private double curDistance()

        {

            const double PIx = 3.141592653589793;
            const double RADIO = 6371;

            double dlat = ((latitude2) * (PIx / 180)) - ((latitude) * (PIx / 180));
            double dlon = ((longtitude2) * (PIx / 180)) - ((longtitude) * (PIx / 180));

            double a = (Math.Sin(dlat / 2) * Math.Sin(dlat / 2)) + Math.Cos((latitude) * (PIx / 180)) * Math.Cos((latitude2) * (PIx / 180)) * (Math.Sin(dlon / 2) * Math.Sin(dlon / 2));
            double angle = 2 * Math.Atan2(Math.Sqrt(a), Math.Sqrt(1 - a));
            double ultimateDistance = (angle * RADIO);

            return ultimateDistance;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Too much code... Please only post the _relevant_ parts.

Comment: I do not see the DistanceGenerator.Coursework that you mention here.  Could you cut down a bit and highlight the problem areas?

Answer (score 6):

`curDistance` in your `Main` method is an *instance* of the `Distance` class.

The `curDistnace` *method* on the `Distnace` class, is `private`, making it unusable outside of the class - you can make it `public`:

```
public double curDistance()
```

You don't want to output the class, but the value of the calculation. For that you need to invoke the *method* `curDistance` on the `Distance` instance (which, you have confusingly also named `curDistance`):

```
Console.WriteLine(curDistance.curDistance());
```

Comment: Thankyou so much. I've been struggling with classes for a while and that has cleared it up in my head :)

Comment: I wasn't even aware you could invoke the method! Thankyou thankyou!